# magento 2 javascript certification exam (dump)

Tags: magento2, certification

Do they have any dump or test questions for magento2 javascript? I would like to try before going to real exam.
Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

Magento does not provide the practice test. Check out the official study guide which includes Example Questions.

> https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-javascript-developer

Try the SwiftOtter Practice test. It's paid but worth a try before going for the real test.

> https://swiftotter.com/magento-2-certified-javascript-developer-practice-test#/

Also, check this free practice test:

> https://www.goconqr.com/en/quiz/17570824/javascript-developer-practice-test-p1-magento-2-certified-

Hope this helps!